# Laravel - toArray() vs getAttributes()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using laravel 6 and using eloquent join to display data from multiple tables.

Consider following code:

```
    $ToGetDefaultAddress 
    = TbPersonaddress::join('tb_cities AS TbCitie','TbCitie.n_CityId_PK', '=', 'tb_personaddresses.n_CityId_FK')
                    ->join('tb_counties AS TbCountie','TbCountie.n_CountyId_PK', '=', 'tb_personaddresses.n_CountyId_FK')
                    ->join('tb_states AS TbState', 'TbState.n_StateId_PK','=' ,'tb_personaddresses.n_StateId_FK')
                    ->select('tb_personaddresses.n_PersonAddressesId_PK','tb_personaddresses.n_PersonId_FK',
                    'tb_personaddresses.d_EffectiveDateFrom','tb_personaddresses.d_EffectiveDateTo',
                    'TbCitie.s_CityCode','TbCitie.s_CityName','TbCountie.s_CountyCode',
                    'TbCountie.s_CountyName','TbState.s_StateCode','TbState.s_StateName')->first();

                    dd("Actual output:::::",$ToGetDefaultAddress);
```

Actual output:[image]

As shown in the above code, I am storing this output in **`$ToGetDefaultAddress`** variable.
Now for getting only the attributes data, both **`toArray()`** and **`getAttributes()`** returns me the same result.

For e.g:

```
$DefaultAddress = $ToGetDefaultAddress->toArray();
```

and

```
$DefaultAddress = $ToGetDefaultAddress->getAttributes();
```

returns me the same output as shown below:
[image]

My question is, what is the difference between using **`toArray()`** and **`getAttributes()`** ? Which one is recommended ? When to use **`toArray()`** and when to use **`getAttributes()`** ?

Comment: Please Accept my answer if you think it was helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at source code:

- [toArray()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1086)
- [getAttributes()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L952)

If you look at them you will see that `toArray()` method returns full model with relationships and attributes and `getAttributes()` returns only model attributes (usually only columns).

This is code fragment from laravel source code:

```
    /**
     * Convert the model instance to an array.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        return array_merge($this->attributesToArray(), $this->relationsToArray());
    }
```

> I saw one method in source code which I didn't know. You can test it too: `->attributesToArray()`

Answer (score 1):

As per Laravel Documentation:

> To convert a model and its loaded relationships to an array, you
>   should use the toArray method. This method is recursive, so all
>   attributes and all relations (including the relations of relations)
>   will be converted to arrays:

```
$user = App\User::with('roles')->first();

return $user->toArray();
```

[Laravel API -> Model -> method_getAttributes](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getAttributes)

> getAttributes(): Get all of the current attributes on the model.

[Laravel -> Eloquent: Serialization-> Serializing To Arrays](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-arrays)